# Google Sheets: Return Entire Column based on Column Name

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet and I want to search for a header name and return everything below the header. I tried searching for formulas in Google but cannot come up with anything.

For example, there are 2 sheets. I want to reference "sheet1" tab and if I type "Sports" in my "sheet2", then I want it to pull the entire "Sports" column from "sheet1" into "sheet2"

[Example Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OYujKItETMLZoHwoQudzqfq_sKsXKt0I6axHQPuj5Ng/edit#gid=829552988).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLUTION

You can try this formula, which uses the CHOOSECOLS() and MATCH() functions to achieve your desired output:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSECOLS(data!$A2:$C,MATCH(A1,data!1:1,0)),"")
```

### OUTPUT

[image]

### REFERENCES

- [CHOOSECOLS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914)
- [MATCH()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)

Comment: To make it dynamic you may try array approach `=CHOOSECOLS(data!A2:C5,INDEX(XMATCH(A1:B1,data!A1:C1)))`.